# Copy table with borders doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, execcommand

I am trying to copy a table using `document.execCommand`. The copying works, but the borders and background color are missing when I paste in an email client. This is happening only when I copy it from Firefox; Chrome works fine.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue for Firefox without external plugins and without using inline styles for the existing table?

```js
function selectElementContents() {
  var el = document.getElementById('div1');
  // Copy textarea, pre, div, etc.
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(el);
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copy command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }

} // end function selectElementContents(el)
```

```css
.table {
  background-color: #faa835;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table th {
  border: 2px solid black
}

.table td {
  border: 2px solid black
}
```

```html
<button id="copy" onclick="selectElementContents()">Copy</button>
<div id="div1">
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Not working table</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Not working table</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[View on CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bPzmvW)

Comment: which  version of Firefox?